# What is difference between command line argument and scanf function in c?

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, scanf

What is difference between command line argument and scanf function in c?
1) what does command line argument mean?
2)If i can take input from user through scanf then what is the need of commad line argument.
3) what is principal difference between scanf and command line rgument

Comment: The difference between a command-line argument and the `scanf` function is the same as the difference between vegetable lasagne and a naked singularity. They have nothing to do with each other :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of standard inputs basically:

> 1.Compile time
>
> 2.Load time
>
> 3.Run time

**1.Compile time:** In this type the programmer himself gives input in code only while compiling.

**2.Load time:** Load time means when the program is being loaded into RAM for execution. In linux terminal in command prompt when you type ./a.out (Or any executable name) you are loading your executable file into RAM, which you've got after compiling it. So while loading the executable along with the executable whatever you are passing through command prompt is treated as **command line arguments.** And that can be used in code some where at run time. In short **command line args** is the input provided at load time.

**3. Run time:** Its the time while program is running or being executed, **scanf ()** is one of the functions that can be used to provide input at run time. So with use of **scanf ()** we can provide input to our program at run time basically.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to call "load time" "invocation time" since the program is not loaded if it is already in memory?

Comment: Frankly I don't know  about "invocation time",  I don't know java but as per this concern the term "load time" is proper because we are loading the executable by that command in prompt right?

Comment: Good explanation. Runtime input can also include stdin datafrom a shell (either through a pipe or a device).

Comment: Load time and runtime are the same thing in single invocation terminating programs, but not in event driven programs like an operating system or a web server.

Answer (score 0):

They're two different ways of getting information into the program.

When you run a program with command line arguments, they're made available to the `main` function as parameters. Since they're C strings, you can read them as such. Running it with command line arguments is basically something like:

```
store picture_of_zx80.jpg myPornDirectory
```

That's running the `store` program with two arguments.

The `scanf` function, on the other hand, reads information in from standard input, something that needs to be provided separately to any command line arguments that may be provided.

Answer (score 0):

A command line argument is added when you start the program.

```
e.g. notepad.exe myletter.txt
```

scanf reads information from the input pipe in other words after the program has started. it also can apply some formatting to the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Command Line arguments are arguments you pass to your program when you start executing it, which then may be used in the program, for instance to control certain behaviour. They can be specified when you run it, for instance, if you had a program called test.exe, you could run it with

```
test.exe someArg
```

From the command line.

The `scanf()` function reads input according to what you specify from the standard input buffer `stdin`. In programs executed on the command line this is typically done to recieve user input, for instance like this:

```
int main(void) {
int input = 0;
scanf("%d",input);
printf("You inputted: %d",input);
return 0;
}
```